# USB MIDI keyboard losing events on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, drivers, midi

SO I have this new USB MIDI keyboard. And I have a Windows 10 PC, where I use GrandOrgue withthis keyboard and another MIDI source.

And I find that just on this new keyboard, not the other MIDI source, from time to time events are lost. AS in a note does not sound (on event lost) or is stuck (off event lost).

This might have something to do with CPU load as the machine is rather basic (AMD A6) and GrandOrgue (plus Win10 itself) can be CPU hungry.

How can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Does this also happen with other software? (Try some MIDI monitor.)

Comment: You may need to run MIDI apps with increased priotity.

Comment: Thanks! I will give this a try. However the issue has to be the driver not the program itself as it does not happen with another MIDI device. Wonder if there is a way to increase priority for this one driver,

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to comment but I want to help. A few things (you'll have to troubleshoot this the hard way, by trying things, start with the easiest things first):

- An AMD A6 will run MIDI devices just fine, even if CPU usage is high. Changing priority of processes/threads won't make a difference here - the USB protocol has robust buffering and error correction, it's not like the old serial port days.
- If the keyboard is currently plugged into a USB hub, try plugging it directly into one of the PCs USB ports.
- If the keyboard is USB powered, but has an option for external power, it may be that the keyboard is designed to draw more power from your USB port than the PC can actually provide. A common issue with certain laptops. This may cause issues like you describe. In which case you'll *have to* give the keyboard external power.
- Some PC designs limit the total USB power draw across all USB ports combined. This is more common on laptops. So if you have other power hungry USB devices attached to your PC, like USB hard drives or fancy LED-lit keyboard/mouse, it may be that there isn't enough power left for your keyboard. Again, if the keyboard supports external power, try use it.
- If your PC has both USB 2.0 and USB 3.x ports, try a USB 2.0 port.
- Try a different and/or shorter USB cable. If your current cable is a USB 3.x cable, find a USB 2.0 one and try that.
- If all else fails, you need to find another PC and test the keyboard on that. Because it is possible (however unlikely) that the keyboard is faulty.
- A faulty keyboard might only be faulty because of its firmware. Many modern keyboards can be updated with new firmware obtainable from the manufacturer's website. Refer to your keyboard's manual to see if you can and instructions on how to do it.

Good luck!